# How to include Different Types of Workitems in Boards of Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, project-management, workitem, azure-boards, agile-project-management

In my Project when I select Project > Boards. In Board Page dropdown, only Epic, Stories and Features type work items appears. I want to display Issues, Test Plans, Tasks and Bugs type work items also there,so that I don't have to navigate to different pages viewing the same. But I am not getting any configuration to perform the same, please suggest me some way how to get in on single Boards?

*(Refer My Project Image & My Workitems Subtask Image screenshots)*

I did view screenshot over some Youtube video, where in boards all type of work items like -Epic, Stories, Features, Issues, Test Plans, Tasks and Bugs are displayed. But that video covers some other topic and not this configuration topic *(Refer Some Sample of Other Oraganization From Video screenshot)*. So I am trying to find a solution for this but not able get it. In my organization's Project board, I  am not getting any such configuration in project Settings.

My project image

[image]

My workitems subtask image

[image]

Sample of some other organization from video]

[image]

Comment: Work items are hierarchal. Bugs can either be treated as requirements (i.e. at the same level as user stories, with child tasks), or as tasks (i.e. as children of user stories). Tasks should be created as the child of a product backlog item or user story, not as the child of a feature or epic. If you want to change these behaviors, you'll have to modify your process template and change the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps contains predefined backlog levels that may include limited set of work item types:

1. Epics - shows epics and child features
2. Features - shows features and child user stories.
3. User stories - shows user stories and child tasks. Additionally it can view bugs: [Show bugs on backlogs and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=azure-devops)
4. Sprints - shows planned user stories and tasks.

Issues and Test plans can not be part of backlogs. Issues are managed with work item queries. Test plans are used in the testing: [Create test plans and test suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops).

You can define your own additional backlog levels: [Portfolio management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/portfolio-management?view=azure-devops),[Customize your backlogs or boards (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops).